# JavaScript redirect in a conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$('submit').on('click', function (){
    var num = document.getElementById('number').value;

    if(num !== ' '){
        window.location = 'userAuth.htnl';
    }
});
```

But after I type something into the DOM element and submit it doesn't redirect. But if I console log my input in the conditional, I see it on the console.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: `$('submit')`  I wasn't aware there was such a thing as a `<submit>` tag.

Comment: It's actually #submit I typed it wrongly here

Comment: Is `#submit` a submit button within a form? Does the page reload instead of redirecting when it's clicked?

Comment: Exactly, it reloads but now I passed an argument in the anonymous function and used the preventDefault() function and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have **'userAuth.htnl';**. Change that to **'userAuth.html';**

```
$('#submit').on('click', function (){
    var num = document.getElementById('number').value;

    if(num !== ' '){
        window.location.replace('userAuth.html');
    }
});
```

Comment: Forgot the replace. Try `window.location.replace('userAuth.html');`

Comment: @user8417421 - Did that work? If not please share the HTML code so I can better help you.